# Replace Data Container of an iOS .ipa File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I have an app that downloads a whole bunch of data from over 100+ APIs upon successful login. I successfully download the data, and then use iExplorer to extract the data container folders (Documents, Library and Tmp) from the fully loaded application.

I would like to take a blank version of the original app, in .ipa format, and insert those data container folders into that fully loaded .ipa file. Then I will be able to take this new fully loaded .ipa, and use a deployment software to deploy it to a bunch of local user's devices. So everyone will have this fully loaded app.

Please, has anyone done this? Please provide some feedback, and don't argue with my methodology, because this has be done this way due to requirements. Maybe there is a step I'm missing? I'm not sure.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible because the Documents, Library and Tmp folders are created on install / demand by the app so unless you have access to the source code you will be unable to pre-populate the database for the app.

Comment: @Rog I do have access to the source code. What can I do in that case? Also, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

With the source code in hand, you can run the app in the simulator (no need for iExplorer), wait for it to download all the files and browse to the folder on your computer where the app was installed.

From there you can put aside any files you want along with their respective folders. If you're using Coredata there should be a SQLITE database file there somewhere (typically in your `Application Support` folder) and this might be all you need but it is hard to tell without looking at your implementation details.

Once you have the files you need set aside, add them to the app bundle via Xcode and create code to check whether files already exist (in which case you don't want to replace them), and if not copy all files needed from the bundle into their respective folders.

Here's some semi pseudo-code for you:

```
NSDictionary *userPrefs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.email];
if (![userPrefs[kInitialSetupCompleted] boolValue])
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSURL *destinationFilePath = ...
  NSURL *seedFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kCoreDataStoreName ofType:nil]];    
  NSError* err = nil;
  if (![fileManager copyItemAtURL:seedPath toURL:destinationFilePath error:&err]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not copy seed data. error: %@", err);
    // Deal with error
  } else {
    // Set user defaults kInitialSetupCompleted to YES
  }
}
```